# How to reduce compile/update time when doing React Native coding on VSCode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode on a daily basis for a variety of projects and I need to increase the time slot/period after which the project is being saved hence being re-compiled by react-native. For example, if I am halfway through writing a simple array operation, it crashes and the app fails which requires me to finish the statement and then re-open the app and maybe refresh it again.

So basically increasing the time until an auto-save operation occurs.

Comment: Why are you saving halfway through your array operation?

Comment: are you talking about auto-save in VS code? if yes, you can disable that.

Comment: yes it is auto save, but I just want to increase auto save time.